# As a rule of thumb, difference in amount of administered items: classically scored vs adaptive (irt-based) tests?

Tags: item-response-theory

I am thinking of developing a new adaptive test. One of the main goals is to shorten existing, classically scored tests. Is there a rule of thumb about how many items are needed to administered compared to classically scored tests?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here. How does the classical test way determine how much information is offered by an adaptive test? I wouldn't think about this particular issue in a classical psychometrics framework since it's full of paradoxes. Think more in terms of how a test understood/analyzed from IRT could be shortened with suitable IRT methods.

Comment: Hi phil, I think you are right. I tried to define the question in a non-expert-ly way because I only need an rule of thumb answer. E.g. when I test someone classically (with just a sum of the good answers as a result) using 15 items, how many items from these 15, as a rule of thumb, would I be needing when using a suitable irt model to score?

Comment: Well, the answer is that it depends. Under IRT some tests measure some abilities better than others (e.g., easy tests discriminate lower ability individuals better but largely have nothing to say about upper ability subjects....think of a math tests with 'addition' questions and why it can't determine whether Einstein or Newton is better at math). So you'd have to look at how much drop in statistical information occurs when using less items across a range of the latent trait, which in turn translates to standard errors for each subject, and determine whether the drop is reasonable or not.